# Percentage of All

Tags: percentages

2% of children in PA have a developmental disability. Of these, 40% live below the poverty line. In comparison, only 35% of children without a developmental disability live below the poverty line.

What percentage of ALL children in PA live below the poverty line?

I think I am overthinking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0.02 * .4 = .008 = $0.8% of the the children are dev. disability and below poverty line.

$0.98*.35 = .343 =$ 34.3% of the children are not dev. disability and below the poverty line.

So 34.3% + .8% = 35.1% of the children are below the poverty line and may or may not have dev. disability

Comment: awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

35.1%
Let's assume there are 100 children in PA.
2% with developmental disability is 2 children. 
40% of these 2 children is 0.8%.

Next, there are 98% of children with no developmental disability (98 children).
35% of these is 34.3%

Sum these up, and it's 35.1%

Comment: Great thanks!!! I was overthinking it.!!